# How can I rotate the position of the tiles in a tile map without rotating the textures

Tags: rotation, godot, godot3

I'm generating a dungeon using pre tilemapped rooms and I want to be able to rotate those rooms to make turns. But unfortunately this also rotates my auto tiled textures and it looks bad.

The rooms are being instanced into a main scene and rotated in that instance

Is there a way I can fix this without having to draw 4 individual tilemaps for all rotations?

optionally a way to copy the current tilemap and rotate all of it in the editor without rotating textures.

I've tried to replace the tileset with a rotated verition of it and use "update_bitmask_area" but this doesn't work as I get an error stating: "Attempt to call function 'update_bitmask_area' in base 'null instance' on a null instance"